# What can you make with Dried Lemon Grass?

Tags: asian-cuisine

A friend went to Cambodia for vacatation,  and brought back many packets of dried lemon grass.  Can someone tell me what its uses are,  and mention some easy to prepare dishes that make use of dried lemon grass?  I can prepare many types of Indian food,  never really come across this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I don't find dried lemon grass that flavorsome and much prefer fresh (usually you can get several big sticks for cheap in the Chinese / Asian supermarkets).

But I'd probably try Thai based dishes - many of their noodle soups (e.g. Tom Yum, chicken noodle soup) will have slices of fresh lemon grass in.  I'd try adding the dry stuff when you are making the stock and see how it works out.

You could also try stir fries and looking around there are several drinks prepared with it (e.g. Lemongrass vodka [(at the bottom of the page)](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/content/knowhow/glossary/lemongrass/) and cooling drinks [here](http://uktv.co.uk/food/recipe/aid/513868)).  Though I suspect again fresh would be better

Comment: Thanks for the links!  Gonna try Aubergine curry with lemon grass and coconut milk :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had good results making soup, where I first boil dried lemon grass and dried galangal in water, then strain, then proceed with making the soup. 
Adds a great flavour and nothing to pick out.

I think if you don't want to strain it, you have to use fresh lemon grass, but even in that case you just chew on it a bit, you don't actually eat the lemon grass; it is too fibrous.

Answer (score 2):

I like to drink infusion made of lemon grass. Hot is nice, and cold with some ginger or watermellon juice is very refreshing.

A strong infusion mixed with coconut milk and simmered to get some consistency makes a great seasoning for light fish meat.

Answer (score 2):

Tea steeped in some lemongrass is a dream. We always had it in India...brilliant. I also use it for chicken dishes. I steep them and utilize the liquid in my cooking. I freeze dry them, grind them with some red chillies and keep that As a 
paste that I include in cooking.